# X509TrustManager - checkServerTrusted not called - is trusted server cert cached or is there a way to get certificate chain?

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, https

In my Android project, I'm using a library (internal to my company) which has a custom HTTP Client with a custom X509TrustManager.

We need to allow a user to choose whether they wish to trust or untrust an untrusted certificate. This much is fine initially, but once the user chooses to trust a certificate, we need a way to remove the cert as a trusted cert if the user decides they don't want to allow to connect to it any more.

The main problem is that the call to the overridden checkServerTrusted is not always called again once we try to connect to a cert the user has chosen to trust. Is the cert cached somewhere to avoid this being called or is there somewhere else in the lifecycle that checks that it's trusted before it gets to this point?  I can't force a call to it as I don't know how to get the certificate chain of the cert I've chosen to trust.

If someone knows either of those things (is it cached, or how to get the cert chain) - that would be brilliant. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to invalidate the SSLSession, that's where it's cached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure how to get the SSLSession. It's not explicit in the code. I have scope to modify the library I'm using, but I can't seem to get the session. I've tried getting the socket from the  SSLSocketFactory to get the session by storing the socket created in createSocket() methods but that was returned as null. Is there a way to get the current socket?

Comment: If you can't get the SSLSocket you can't get the SSLSession. 'Current socket' isn't well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your help @EJP . I ended up closing any open connections using closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  , which in turn invalidated the SSLSession.

Comment: No it didn't. SSL Sessions outlive individual connections. That's what they're for.

Comment: Is there a way to define SSLSession cache timeout ? [This](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html) seems to be it but I don't know how to set it for the application at JVM level